# GraphDB- Python Sparql query returning : http status (404)

Tags: python, sparql, rdf, semantic-web, graphdb

I am trying to execute following Sparql query

```
select * where { 
    ?s ?p ?o .
} limit 100
```

It runs well and produces result as required in http://localhost:7200/sparql i.e. GraphDB Workbench.
I would like to use python to do the same query and for this  I generated following  query URL by clicking “Get URL to current query" in GraphDB interface.

```
http://localhost:7200/sparql?name=&infer=true&sameAs=false&query=select+*+where+%7B+%0A%09%3Fs+%3Fp+%3Fo+.%0A%7D+limit+100+%0A&execute=
```

I tried writing Python code for this

```
 import pycurl
 from StringIO import StringIO
 url="http://localhost:7200/sparql?name=&infer=true&sameAs=false&query=select+*+where+%7B+%0A%09%3Fs+%3Fp+%3Fo+.%0A%7D+limit+100+%0A&execute="
 response_buffer = StringIO()
 curl = pycurl.Curl()
 curl.setopt(curl.URL,url)
 curl.setopt(curl.USERPWD, '%s:%s' % (' ' , ' '))
 curl.setopt(curl.WRITEFUNCTION, response_buffer.write)
 curl.perform()
 curl.close()
 response_value = response_buffer.getvalue()
 print response_value
```

However this returns :Error - http status (404) - No message, look at the server logs for more information

Do I need to do any additional setting for querying the GraphDB in Python.
Could I get some guidance on How to query GraphDB using Python and Sparql?

Comment: Both URLs do not match in your example.

Comment: Yes that got altered while typing here.. but originally both are same while trying.. Thanks for comment.. have edited the typo here..

Comment: You might want to check out [sparql-wrapper](https://rdflib.github.io/sparqlwrapper/), it's much nicer to query GraphDB with than curl...

Answer (score 4):

GraphDB database exposes a SPARQL endpoint for each RDF repository. The correct SPARQL endpoint address can be copied from the Workbench's interface Setup > Repositories > the link icon next to the repository name ("Copy Repository URL to Clipboard").

Your HTTP request should look like:

```
http://localhost:7200/repositories/%repositoryID%?name=&infer=true&sameAs=false&query=select+*+where+%7B+%0A%09%3Fs+%3Fp+%3Fo+.%0A%7D+limit+100+%0A&execute=
```

where the ***%repositoryID%*** value is the id of the repository.